# Installing Kivy in Anaconda

Tags: installation, kivy, anaconda

I am trying to install Kivy in Anaconda 3 4.1.1 in Windows 7. But I couldn't find a proper user guide to instruct me how to do so. But so far I was able to find instructions to install it on OS X on the link https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Connecting-Kivy-with-Anaconda-(OSX). But I couldn't find a one for Windows operating systems.

Can anyone provide me with instructions on how to install Kivy in Anaconda?

Answer (score 18):

Use anaconda search for search the package names and conda install to install:

```
anaconda search -t conda kivy
```

For Windows:

```
conda install -c krisvanneste kivy=1.8.0
```

For Linux:

```
conda install -c moritzimend kivy=1.9.0
```

For Mac:

```
conda install -c akode kivy=1.9.1
```

Comment: For Mac users `akode` channel only contain Kivy compatible with Python 2.7.

Comment: same for windows.

Comment: This is superseded by the current pip package, which works fine on Windows.

Comment: The `conda-forge` channel is the official kivy anaconda release channel.

Answer (score 6):

Kivy now has official Anaconda releases on all platforms. You can install it with:

```
conda install kivy -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/jiayi_anaconda kivy
```

this will work fine.

Comment: Please don't install kivy from random channels, which are not officially supported and kivy developers have no control over. Use the official kivy conda distribution instead.