# linux how to install kivy with conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

i want to add kivy in my anaconda python.
i use anaconda3 last version with python3.6 on Centos 7 64bits

i try to use last version in anaconda cloud :
./conda install --force --no-deps -c wgarcia kivy
or
./conda install --force --no-deps -c wgarcia kivy=1.9.1

i try with other version in other repo (1.9.0,1.8...) but i have same error

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - kivy=1.9.1
  - sphinx
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

please, how to install Kivy (1.10 ?) in my anaconda ?

Comment: Please check this post [Installing Kivy in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981491/installing-kivy-in-anaconda)

Comment: i view this post before posted but this command :
conda install -c moritzimend kivy=1.9.0 

not work, i have same error i try with kivy=1.9.1, or 1.10.0...etc not work